# How to create my own custom simple action in D8?

Tags: plugins, 8

I'm creating a view that is used to review migrated content that was flagged for review during the migration process. I want to provide a bulk action on this view that allows the user to select a bunch and mark them as "resolved".

I created a custom action to do this following some guidance from https://www.drupal.org/node/2330631:

`config/install/pu_news_migrate.action.resolve_news_migration_flag.yml`

```
langcode: en
status: true
dependencies:
  module:
    - node
id: resolve_news_migration_flag
label: 'Resolve news migration flag'
type: node
plugin: resolve_news_migration_flag
configuration: {  }
```

And created the action plugin implementation:

`src/Plugin/Action/ResolveNewsMigrationFlag.php

```
<?php

namespace Drupal\pu_news_migrate\Plugin\Action;

use Drupal\Core\Action\ActionBase;
use Drupal\Core\Session\AccountInterface;

/**
 * Removes the "needs review" flag on a migrated news article.
 *
 * @Action(
 *   id = "resolve_news_migration_flag",
 *   label = @Translation("Resolve news migration flag"),
 *   type = "node"
 * )
 */
class ResolveNewsMigrationFlag extends ActionBase {

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function execute($node = NULL) {
    if ($node) {
      /** @var \Drupal\node\NodeInterface $node */
      if (!$node->hasField('field_news_migration_review')) {
        throw new \RuntimeException("News migration field not found on node.");
      }
      $node->set('field_news_migration_review', FALSE);
      $node->save();
    }
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function access($object, AccountInterface $account = NULL, $return_as_object = FALSE) {
    /** @var \Drupal\node\NodeInterface $object */
    $result = $object->field_news_migration_review->access('edit', $account, TRUE)
      ->andIf($object->access('update', $account, TRUE));

    return $return_as_object ? $result : $result->isAllowed();
  }

}
```

I also added a schema file: `config/schema/pu_news_migrate.schema.yml`:

```
action.configuration.resolve_news_migration_flag:
  type: resolve_news_migration_flag
  label: 'Remove the "needs review" flag from a migrated article.'
```

I uninstalled the module and re-installed it so that the action definition is loaded into Drupal's config.

However, when I view the list of actions I can select in views, it doesn't appear there. I enabled the "Actions" module which displays a list of all actions, and it does not appear there either.

What did I do wrong here?

Comment: Did you also provide a schema.yml file? Check the node module for an example. I also think the name of the file needs to be _system.action...._ not _pu_news_migrate_

Comment: Yes, just updated question with that snippet

Comment: Did you try renaming the plugin yaml file name to _system.action.._, uninstalling and reinstalling? The actions in node and user are named this way, not node.action.blahblah.

Comment: Kevin, that was it! If you post that as an answer I can can accept your answer and bounty.

Comment: I thought so, just wanted to double check. Answer added.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Action plugin yaml definitions need to be prefixed with the name `system.action.action_name.yml`, and not `mymodule.action_name.yml`.

For reference, check the provided action plugins for node and user module in core in their `config/install` and `config/schema` folders.

Uninstall the module, rename the files, and install the module again so the changes are picked up. You should then see your custom action.

So:

`config/install/system.action.resolve_news_migration_flag.yml`